# IBM Watson Natural Language Understanding

Tags: html, node.js, ejs, ibm-watson, websphere

Error: Cannot find module 'ibm-watson/natural-language-understanding/v1.js'
Require stack:

I am now trying to extract keywords by using IBM Watson Natural Language Understanding API. I follow the instruction and have installed the watson_developer_cloud. However, I met an error when import the NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1. Could you help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

That you haven’t provided any code to help us work out what could be happening in your case leads me to suspect that you haven’t run `non install ibm-watson`